# Debug and release configurations for global variable in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-phone-8

I have two  different URL for debug and release mode:  "http://release.myurl.com/" and "http://debug.myurl.com/".

What better way to declare global property in Windows Phone 8? Which is dependent on the mode used different constants and to be able to use them in C# and XAML.

Comment: Doesn't windows phone projects use app.config? If they do, it's quite easy to set up Debug and release transformations on the AppSettings which will automatically change the constants for you during build.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail, please?

Comment: Hmm, from looking around, it seems like indeed, app.configs are not used on Windows Phone, so I don't think my solution helps you in this situation :(

Comment: yeah, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157153/app-config-on-windows-phone-7 :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at a app.xaml.cs file of a fresh windows phone project, you'll notice this line:
`if (Debugger.IsAttached) {`

That's how to detect if the debugger is attached or not. Now ofcourse thats not yet exactly what you want. You might use compiler directives like this to have different code for debug mode:

```
#if DEBUG
// code that runs (and even only gets compiled in) when in debug build mode
#else
// not debug mode
#endif
```